# Django: The view didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead. When Override Form_Valid

Tags: python, python-3.x, django, sockets, python-sockets

I overrode the form_valid method on my `RobotDetail` view but whenever I try to use the view I get the error `The view dashboard.views.RobotDetail didn't return an HttpResponse object. It returned None instead.` If anybody knows how to fix this it would be super appreciated!
VIEW

```
from django.shortcuts import render
from django.views.generic import ListView, DetailView, UpdateView
from .models import Robot
from .forms import RobotUpdateForm
import socket
import threading
HEADER = 64
PORT = 6060
SERVER = socket.gethostbyname(socket.gethostname())
ADDR = (SERVER, PORT)
FORMAT = 'utf-8'
DISCONNECT_MESSAGE = "!DISCONNECT!"

class RobotDetail(UpdateView):
    model = Robot
    form_class = RobotUpdateForm
    template_name = 'dashboard/robotdetail.html'

    def form_valid(self, form):
        self.object = form.save()
        client = socket.socket(socket.AF_INET, socket.SOCK_STREAM)
        client.connect(ADDR)

        def send(msg):
            message = msg.encode(FORMAT)
            msg_length = len(message)
            send_length = str(msg_length).encode(FORMAT)
            send_length += b' ' * (HEADER - len(send_length))
            client.send(send_length)
            client.send(message)

        send("Hello World!")
        send("Hello Andrew")
        send("Hello")
        send(DISCONNECT_MESSAGE)
```

MODEL

```
class Robot(models.Model):
    def fetch_choices():
        scope = [REDACTED]
        creds = ServiceAccountCredentials.from_json_keyfile_name("dashboard/Files/creds.json", scope)
        client = gspread.authorize(creds)
        sheet = client.open("tutorial").sheet1
        path_names = []
        path_name_fetch =  sheet.col_values(1)
        for i in path_name_fetch:
            if (i, i) not in path_names:
                path_names.append((i, i))
        return path_names

    name = models.CharField(max_length=200)
    path_options = models.CharField(choices=fetch_choices(), default=fetch_choices(), max_length=100)
    status_choices = [('waiting', 'waiting'), ('running', 'running'), ('stuck', 'stuck')]
    current_status = models.CharField(choices=status_choices, default=status_choices[0], max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.name + ' | Current Status: ' + self.current_status

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('dashboard-home')
```

TEMPLATE

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <title>Dashboard</title>
</head>
<body>
    {% extends 'theblog/base.html' %}
    {% block content %}
        <h1>Dispatcher</h1>
        <form method="POST">
            {% csrf_token %}
            {{ form.as_p}}
            <button class="btn btn-secondary">Dispatch</button>
        </form>
    {% endblock %}
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Your `form_valid` should return a HTTP response.

Comment: Does it matter what the render is for the socket or can I just render the page I am looking for?

Comment: @WillemVanOnsem I added a return render but because it is a CBV I can't get `request` in. Any ideas why?

Comment: you can use `self.request`.